# How to use webpack to concat html pieces?

Tags: webpack

For example, I have a main entry html file:

```
<div>
   <!-- I'd like to include a html partial here -->
</div>
```

And I have a partial html

```
<span>I'm a partial html piece</span>
```

I hope that I can use webpack to generate a final html like below:

```
<div>
  <span>I'm a partial html piece</span>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this with webpack plugin/loaders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a couple of loaders to achieve this:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html#templating

---

For example:

[html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader)

```
<div>${require('./partials/gallery.html')}</div>
```

[ejs-html-loader](https://github.com/akim-mcmath/ejs-html-loader)

```
<% include some/file %>
```

Comment: I have same probleme and when i use <div>${require('./partials/gallery.html')}</div> the require isn't interpretate

Comment: I can't get this to work, can you give a working example?

Comment: @VishalSharma, did you find out how to do it?

Comment: @alex ended up writing my own script.

Comment: yes for me also not working, i installed "npm i -D html-loader" and then  i write this - "<div>${require("html-loader!./file.html")}</div>" - code in index.html inside the body. and also i included the module {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [ 'file-loader?name=[./html][name].[ext]!extract-loader!html-loader' ]
            }

Comment: @VishalSharma how did you do that?

Comment: To make it work you need to enable `interpolate` Here is sample code `{
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        interpolate:true,
                        minimize: true
                        /*removeComments: false,
                         collapseWhitespace: true*/
                    }
                }],
            }`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this plugin [github.com/bazilio91/ejs-compiled-loader](http://github.com/bazilio91/ejs-compiled-loader):

```
{ test: /\.ejs$/, use: 'ejs-compiled-loader' }
```

Change your `.html`  files in `.ejs`  and your `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to point to the right `.ejs`  template:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/views/index.ejs',
    filename: 'index.html',
    title: 'Home',
    chunks: ['index']
})
```

You can import partials, variables, and assets in `.ejs` files:

`src/views/partials/head.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>
```

`src/js/ejs_variables.js`:

```
const hello = 'Hello!';
const bye = 'Bye!';

export {hello, bye}
```

`src/views/index.ejs`:

```
<% include src/views/partials/head.ejs %>
<body>    
  <h2><%= require("../js/ejs_variables.js").hello %></h2>

  <img src=<%= require("../../assets/sample_image.jpg") %> />

  <h2><%= require("../js/ejs_variables.js").bye %></h2>
</body>
```

A note, when you include a partial the path must be relative to the root of your project.

I answered the same question here [stackoverflow.com/a/48750048/7448956](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750048/7448956).

Comment: you save my life