# Webpack: load images from inline style (background-image)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-html-loader

I have a problem with loading an image using webpack.

When I use an image tag on an html page, everything works fine:

```
 <img src="../../content/images/logo.png">
```

But I also have a need to use inline styles:

```
<div style="background-image: url('../../content/images/logo.png')">
```

In this case, webpack doesn't resolve the images and leaves the string in the `url()` untouched.

Webpack config:

```
        module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'awesome-typescript-loader'
                ],
                exclude: ['node_modules/generator-jhipster']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: true,
                    caseSensitive: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes:false,
                    minifyJS:false,
                    minifyCSS:false
                },
                exclude: ['./src/main/webapp/index.html']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
            },
            {
                test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
            },
            {
                test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
                loaders: ['file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=/images/[hash].[ext]']
            }
        ]
    },
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: There's an unresolved issue about this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/131

Comment: There's also a pull request about this, and it has been there since 2020, but still not get merged  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/pull/279

Comment: The alternative I am taking now is to use CopyWebpackPlugin to copy all my background-image source right into /dist, just check my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

You might require your ´html´ file with [interpolation flag enabled](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#interpolation):

```
require("html-loader?interpolate!./your-file.html");
```

...and then require your inlined-style background image like:

```
<div style="background-image: url('${require(`../../content/images/logo.png`)}')">
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `${require('')}` in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On webpack 5, the correct answer will be to use your `html-loader`.

Change your inline styles:

```
 ## Heading ##<div background-image="../../content/images/logo.png">
```

and your `html-loader`:

```
  {
    test: /\.html$/i,
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      minimize: true,
      attributes: {
        list: [
          '...',// All default supported tags and attributes
          {
            tag: 'div',
            attribute: 'data-background',
            type: 'src',
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#attributes) for more details.

Comment: HTML should be `<div data-background="../../content/images/logo.png">`. Please notice attribute name `data-background` instead of `background-image` in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Googled myself for solution, and decided to make a loader.
https://github.com/apotap2/url-replace-loader
It's just 20 lines of code :D it just that replaces *every* 'url(.*)' with require() so you can use it with file-loader. If you need more complicated logic it seems it's faster to make a loader yourself.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to install your loader. I'm only used to install with npm :/ Could you help me with that? I'm assuming you just need to rename the "url-replace-loader-master" to "url-replace-loader" and drop it in node_modules. But I can't make it work after that.

Comment: you can install via npm install from git repos: `npm install url#branch`, so in my case it can be `npm install https://github.com/apotap2/url-replace-loader`.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution would be (if you dont want to use interpolate flag)

```
$scope.imageToUse =  require(`../../content/images/logo.png`)
```

in your controller

and use directly in your background: url({{imageToUse }})

Internally webpack will encode image to base64 and that will be assigned to imageToUse variable which than will rendered to your html page.

## This solution is related to implementing webpack in Angular 1.X project. Similar approach can be applied in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution for me was to use `interpolate` option in Webpack as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750048/1319182).

```
{
  test: /\.(html)$/,
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/views'),
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      interpolate: true
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your HTML

```
 <div style="background-image: url('${require('../../content/images/logo.png')')">
```

Comment: the `interpolate` option is now removed, so this is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic just:

```
<div class="background-design-element" style="background-image: url('<%= require('./../assets/images/test.jpg') %>')"></div>
```

Key is to remember: <%= =%>
It can actually be this simple - :-)

Answer (score 0):

### `interpolate` option is removed Since `1.0.0`

check the change log here : https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Since `1.0.0` , `interpolate` option is removed, so using `url('{require(...)}')` is no longer possible.

The alternative I am taking now is to use `CopyWebpackPlugin` to clone all background-image source into `dist` (the ouput) folder, and use relative path to get source file in html.

```html
<div style="background-image:url('../assets/images/xx.png')">
```

But using this way you will also lose the tree-shaking of those background-images source, and it's actually not possible to use source alias in url(), so it is just a temporary way :(

```js
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
...

plugins: [
   ...,
   new CopyPlugin(
      {
        patterns: [
          ...
          { 
            from: 'src/assets/images/background-image',
            to: 'assets/images/background-image',
          }
          
        ]
      }
    )

]
```