# How to include raw static html file into another html file with webpack

Tags: html, webpack, webpack-html-loader

I have a `header.html` file

```
<header>
  <nav>
    ... some code here ...
  </nav>
</header>
```

And I have an `index.html` file too where I want to include this header.html.

My index.html looks like this:

```
<body>
  ${require('./header.html')}
  <div class="content">
    <!-- some content here -->
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <!-- some content here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm using this `webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/js/index.js', ...],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'js/index.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ['html-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/main.html',
      filename: 'main.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

I tried to include header.html like this:

```
${require('./header.html')}
```

and this too:

```
<%= require('./header.html') %>
```

tried to import in js/index.js file with this line:

```
import header from 'html-loader!../header.html';
```

...combined with this:

```
${require('./header.html')}
```

and this:

```
${require(header)}
```

but nothing work. I just give back my `${require ...}` code as plain text in index.html, and nothing included.

Any idea how to include the header.html file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: This answer is not valid anymore with `html-loader` > 0.5.5**

You need to enable `interpolation` like this:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            interpolate: true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Source for my answer, [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374187/how-can-i-provide-parameters-for-webpack-html-loader-interpolation).

Comment: the solution  don't support any more. Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the interpolate option was removed in html-loader v1.0.0. The solution works with html-loader v0.5.5 and ${require('./header.html')}

Comment: is there any option / solution instead of interpolation?

Comment: how can we interpolate now? :(