# HTML includer developer tool

Tags: html, webpack, developer-tools

Does a developer tool exists what can include a HTML file into another one? For example:

image.html:

```
<img src="img/hero.jpg" alt="Hello World">
```

main.html:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<!-- some content -->
<%= include 'image.html' %>
<!-- some other content -->
</body>
</html>
```

The syntax is whatever, I think this is the EJS webpack loader's syntax, but this is an example.

I'm looking for this because html webpack's html-loader not working.

Good answer can be a working `webpack.config.js` file or another developer tool too.

Comment: it's just pure html

Comment: then I'm not sure, PHP be my ballgame - google have nothing?

Comment: I found noting useful in Google. I'm sure there is a tool, just I'm using wrong keywords to search, but I have no idea...

Comment: This looks like an typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Try to fix what is not working with html-loader instead?

Comment: I have a question about html-loader, but don't have answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527619/how-to-include-raw-static-html-file-into-another-html-file-with-webpack

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527619/how-to-include-raw-static-html-file-into-another-html-file-with-webpack#51569278). Webpack can handle the problem with `html-loader` `interpolation` option.

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery to embed a piece of HTML into an other file.

```
$("#MyElement").load("navigation.html");


<div id="MyElement"></div>
```

Comment: Normal JavaScript can do it pretty easily. No need to run a library for just that.

Comment: this is not a javascript / jQuery level problem

Answer (score -1):

Use `jquery ajax load`

```
$( "body" ).load( "image.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: not a jquery level problem... I want to create a HTML file what contain the other HTML file's code.